# How to collect client data when we redirect using 301 redirect?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, redirect

There is a system like [Clickmeter](http://www.clickmeter.com/) that allows people to create a smart link for their banner ads. Here is a short explanation of the system. You can enter a URL as the landing page and system gives you back a special URL to put instead of the original. Now if someone clicks on the special link, he will be redirected to the landing page that you wanted to.

I am developing something like that but here is the trouble. I must use 301 redirect because of some SEO things, and 301 redirect is only available in server side as I know. But I want to get some client data such as browser name, operating system model and browser language before redirecting the client. And I am doing this part in javascript, absolutely client side.

I dont know what to do or if I am wrong about something else. But I know that [Clickmeter](http://www.clickmeter.com/) is doing exactly the thing that I want to. They get some client data and then do 301 redirect. Here is a sample link of CLickmeter: http://9nl.it/vz0d

Comment: Please add code, not links (nobody should go to a link from a question to understand it). And even if you _have to_ add a link, please don't add one that has been obscured with a URL shortener and people cannot tell what's on the other side.

Comment: Thank you for your comment @AlvaroMontoro. The links that I put in the question is for someone who wants to know more about the issue. The question is simple. I am looking for 301 redirecting and getting client side data in a same time. Thank you again for your attention

Answer (score 0):

You don't get the client's data in the client's side. You do it in the server side by reading and processing the `Request.UserAgent` before doing the 301 redirection:

```
// get the User Agent
string userAgentText = HttpContext.Current.Request.UserAgent;

// Process the User Agent, and extract the information you want: browser, OS, version...
...

// Make the 301 redirection to the target URL programmatically
HttpContext.Current.Response.Status = "301 Moved Permanently";
HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Location", TARGET_URL);
```

---

You could get similar information in JavaScript by using `window.navigator.userAgent` (and AJAX to send the data on click), but I would not recommend this solution for two reasons reasons:

- If you are providing just a URL (your service sounds like a URL shortener), you cannot inject the JavaScript code.
- If the user has JavaScript disabled, this solution will not work at all.

---

To find more information on how this could be done, read these questions:

- [How do I get just the OS from Request.UserAgent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19714185/how-do-i-get-just-the-os-from-request-useragent)
- [What is the difference between Request.UserAgent and Request.Browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10780418/what-is-the-difference-between-request-useragent-and-request-browser)
- [301 redirect in asp.net 4.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10673303/301-redirect-in-asp-net-4-0)
- [How can you detect the version of a browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5916900/how-can-you-detect-the-version-of-a-browser) (if you still decide to go with a JS approach)